# Toshiba TOSVERT VF-S15 VFD and USB001Z

Tags: usb, hardware

I'm currently trying to drive an AC Motor using the TOSHIBA TOSVERT VF-S15 Inverter and the USB-to-serial communication unit USB001Z.
The problem is that the rpi recognized the USB001Z but it seems that there is no driver for it under raspbian.
Calling dmesg after plug it in my rpi give me :

> [ 5195.175931] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd 
>   [ 5195.308466] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=e040
>   [ 5195.308468] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>   [ 5195.308470] usb 1-3: Product: USB001Z
>   [ 5195.308471] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: TSIJ
>   [ 5195.308472] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: USB001ZX

But using lsusb i got this

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:e040 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd

So it's based on FTDI chip
and lsub -t give me this :

> Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M

So it's look like it's not natively supported. The USB001Z manufacturer (Toshiba) provide windows driver only so i suppose it's only compatible with windows (the user manual mention windows as the applicable OS).

After some research, i have found that Linuxcnc has driver for [VF-S11](http://linuxcnc.org/docs/html/drivers/vfs11.html)
which is close to the VF-S15 so i was wondering if i can compile the [linuxcnc HAL](https://github.com/araisrobo/linuxcnc/tree/master/src/hal/user_comps/vfs11_vfd) for raspbian. If not possible which USB-to-serial could i use instead of USB001Z ?

Thanks for your help !